# What does this debug assertion failed mean?

Tags: c++

> Expression: header->_block_use == block_use || header->_block_use ==
> _CRT_BLOCK && block_use == _NORMAL_BLOCK

What does this mean? It has something to do with a header?

I found in my code where after I step over it returns the debug assertion failure, just this one line of code works in other projects.

Is there a linker setting or c/c++ setting that I have to remove?

Comment: Can we get some context around that? Where is this code? Please give us a [mcve]

Comment: It has a lot to do with the code you are running.  This is a message intended for someone who can see the code, which currently is only you.

Comment: For me, it looks like the memory heap is corrupted and MSVC `malloc` complains that it found invalid memory block in the chain.

Comment: @prapin's answer is correct - you've got some dodgy code which is writing out fo bounds or after the lifetime has ended. Its just the debug heap implementation picking it up. Note its not necessarily the line which is currently running which is corrupting memory - it could've happened a while before - the current line just detects it.

Comment: Double delete? Have a class that violates the rule of 3/5 /0?

Answer (score 6):

The assertion that you are hitting is part of the Microsoft Visual C/C++ runtime libraries, specifically related to the [debug heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019). Calling `malloc`/`free` and using the `new`/`delete` operators leads to calls to the CRT heap functions, which perform internal consistency checks using these assertions.

It's very likely that the assertion is hit as a result of a memory safety bug, for example trying to delete a garbage pointer, double-free, etc. If you are unable to find it, the ASAN tool can help by keeping closer track of memory operations and raising errors when your code does invalid things. Without these close checks, mistakes in your code can corrupt a data structure, and the crash could occur much, much later in unrelated code.

For Visual Studio, it involves [a few steps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/): the "C++ AddressSanitizer" feature must be installed using the Visual Studio installer, and the address sanitizer must be enabled in the project properties under C/C++ -> General.

Answer (score 1):

I also get this assertion at times as well. Upon further looking at the code in `debug_heap.cpp` I think there is a bug.

shouldn't

```cpp
_ASSERTE(header->_block_use == block_use || header->_block_use == _CRT_BLOCK && block_use == _NORMAL_BLOCK);
```

be

```cpp
_ASSERTE(header->_block_use == block_use || header->_block_use == _CRT_BLOCK || block_use == _NORMAL_BLOCK);
```

It really isn't possible for `block_use` to be both `_CRT_BLOCK AND _NORMAL_BLOCK` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Languages such as C and C++ offer an `assert(...expression...)` facility that is typically used during debugging ... and omitted from the final delivered product.  The `..expression...` being "something that should always be False."

If the `expression` turns out *not* to be False, then it throws a runtime exception containing the exact text of `expression`.  Which is exactly what a *developer* would like to see, because: *"the whole idea is that this should never, ever, ever happen!"*

Ordinarily, *published* versions of applications are compiled in such a way that all of the `assert()` statements are ignored: they are "no-ops."